# How do I retrieve extras from the launched app with cordova-plugin-app-launcher

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am trying to **pass a parameter** to another application.

I am using [cordova-plugin-app-launcher](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-app-launcher) to launch the other application.

Both applications are wrapped by **Cordova** and only are available on **Android**.

In this moment I don't have access to the code of the second application which is launched, so I can't test a solution right now.

I saw the GitHub documentation talks about **extras**, and for the launch part would be something like this:

```
window.plugins.launcher.launch({uri:'fb://profile', extras: [{"name":"param1", "value":"VALUE1", "dataType":"String"}]}, successCallback, errorCallback);
```

I would like to know how to retrieve this extra on the launched app (maybe on the App.controller.js?).

### EDIT

I think this can be handled by [this other plugin](https://github.com/napolitano/cordova-plugin-intent#get-cordova-intent)

```
document.addEventListener('deviceReady', function(){
window.plugins.intent.getCordovaIntent(function (Intent) {
        console.log(Intent);
    }, function () {
        console.log('Error');
    });
}
```

Can someone please confirm is this is the way to do this or this is a good/bad practice? I would like to know if you have any suggestion to perform this logic I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova apps cannot capture startup parameters out of the box.

Someone has tried and has a fix for iOS I believe but I haven't seen anything for Android.
See [this issue](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/723)

You might also want to look into https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-intent